# Re-using MVC4 components in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, adapter, code-reuse

I have a sizable investment in an MVC4 site that has a large array of custom model binders, value providers etc.

I now want to add some WebAPI controllers to the site and re-use some of the MVC4 components. It appears that there are many parallel concepts in MVC and WebAPI (e.g. model binding), but the base classes and interfaces live in separate namespaces, meaning the types are not interchangeable.

Is there an established pattern for adapting MVC classes to their WebAPI equivalents? Specifically I'm interested in being able to reuse a `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder` as a  `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder`.

Comment: Be more specific please.  What classes and interfaces live in different namespaces?  Your question is much much too vague.

Comment: I am afraid that there's not much that could be reused. ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API are two completely different frameworks solving 2 completely different problems. The first is used to build web UIs and the second is used to build web APIs.

Comment: maybe you can register WebApi Model Binder into MVC and viceversa, not sure thought.

Answer (score 2):

The problem are not the interfaces but the fact that the model binding rules used by the two model binders are completely different and based on different concepts. That's why the interfaces are defined in two different namespaces otherwise they would have used exactly the same interface. There is a parallelism between the two interfaces but they represent two different concepts. In other words the syntax is similar but the semantic is different so you cannot have a one to one mapping among them

Comment: Right.... but the interfaces are the same.  Hence why I was asking about an adapter.

Comment: the problem are not the interface but the fact that the model binding rules used by the two model binders are completely different and based on different concepts. That's why the interfaces are defined in two different namespaces otherwise they would have used exactly the same interface. There is a parallelism between the two interfaces but they represent two different concepts. In other words the syntax is similar but the semantic is different so you cannot have a one to one mapping among them